# Matlab symbolic solver giving different solution when I use subs to give values to consants and when I directly apply the numbers

Tags: matlab, solver, symbolic-computation

My problem is the following (has to do with movement of vehicles) :  I use dsolve in Matlab to solve a differential equation about the jerk (which is the derivative of the acceleration) and then I integrate the solution three times to get the acceleration, the speed and the position. I add the necessary integral constants in every integration.

Then in order to calculate all the constants (6 in total), I use solve and 6 equations which have to do with the initial position, speed, acceleration and jerk etc. So now I have a symbolic expression for each constant.

In order to give numeric values to these constants, I use two ways. One is to use double(vpa(subs(symb_expression,{ A B C}, {no1,no2,no3}))) which works fine but is really slow. In order to make it faster I thought of taking the symbolic expression and make it a "normal" calculation using a function.[ For example if the symbolic expression is C1=a+b*exp(v1/v2), I just copy and paste this in a function which takes as inputs a,b,v1 and v2 and returns C1. ] My expressions are however very long ones.

The problem is that with the first method I get exactly what I want whereas with the second it gets crazy when it approaches the end of the simulation. (In the first part i.e for times < 14 they are exactly the same although it cannot be seen because the final values in the bug case are very big and force the graph to be scaled differently). [image: normal case][image: bug?] The problem can be seen in the upper left and bottom right graphs (consider the other ones irrelevant).

I thought it has to do with the precision and tried increasing the *digits* value but it did not solve the problem.

Any ideas would be more than welcome!

Comment: Instead of copy&paste, try this function to convert: http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html?refresh=true

Comment: I tried this but the result is unfortunately the same

Comment: You may be dealing with numeric precision issues. Copy-pasting data is never a good idea, very prone mistakes, and should be avoided in most cases – Are you sure you're getting the exact values? It looks like you're dealing with exponentials – are you sure that you don't have under- or overflow when converting to double precision? Even converting to variable precision with `vpa` can cause issue in some cases if your value of `digits is not sufficiently high for the particular problem. It's impossible to say more without real runnable code that replicates the issue at hand.